# Add a class to div if a product is in the cart

Tags: shopify, addclass, cart, liquid

Is it possible to see if an item is already in the cart and add a class to div on the product page?

I was hoping something like:

```
   {% for line_item in cart.items %}
     {% if line_item.title = product.title %}
       {% assign incart = "in-cart" %}
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
```

would do this: `{% if line_item.title = product.title %}` but Shopify doesn't like it. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

line_item.title is different than product.title. Because line_item.title is the variant of the product which is in the cart.
Say product title is Shirt
And the line_item.title will be Shirt-Red(red variant)

So try this `line_item.product.title`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
{% assign in_cart = false %}
{% for item in cart.items %}
  {% if item.product.handle == product.handle %}
    {% assign in_cart = true %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if in_cart == true %}
  Product is already in the cart...
{% endif %}
```

Also note that in your if statement you should use `==`, not `=`.